# How can I Z-combine multiple render layers

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers

I have a problem while compositing my render layers. There is a butterfly that goes through a jungle (images as plane). It appears on the foreground, and goes to the background followed by a camera.

So I created a render layer for the butterfly alone, and other render layers for the jungle in order to color grade elements separately.

The problem is that my butterfly moves in depth. I don't know what is the best way to composite my render layers ( I am new to compositing in blender).

I tried to do that with the Z-combine node but it gives me strange result, see the images below:

[image]
[image]

It may be the wrong method? What about masking the butterfly with the alpha channel of foreground render-layers? I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I found out the solution. I thought that the order you plug render layers didn't matter, but I was wrong.

Here are two screenshots : one in the right order (foreground render to background render-layers)
[image: right order]

Another in the wrong order (butterfly still plugged first, but followed by background render-layers and and at last foreground render layers).
[image: wrong order]

Comment: Amateur question, but how did you get all the layers to render at the same time??

Comment: I moved my objects to a specific layer, and then assigned those layers to render layers(or ciew layers?) which are then assembled with the composite node. This is the old way though, as blender introduced collection with the 2.8 series. You may want google it( or duckduckgo it ;) ): « blender collection render layers composite » for exemple.