# How to alpha mask a texture only when the object is behind other objects?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers, masking

I have an animated object (A) that goes behind other objects (B) 
and has it's own render layer.
All my objects are actually textures mapped on planes (i use blender as a replacement of after effects), so i can't use the solid as a mask.

Edit: here is a screenshot of the compositor
[image]

My question is : how to leave A unmasked when it is over B, and mask it when it is behind?

Thanks

Comment: @Mr Zak I tryied but i got strange results, as described in this topic [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81251/how-can-i-z-combine-multiple-render-layers)_italic_**bold** 'code'

Comment: @Mr Zak I pluged all the render layers with no regards on the order . I checked the option "use alpha" and "anti alias z"

Comment: The reason I asked was to know if you use Z output from render layers node to the ZCombine input.

Comment: Ok sorry. I uses the Z output indeed. But do you if i have to pay attention to the order ? L'île i would do with an Alpha over node?

Comment: Afaik it doesn't matter although it's preferable to feed it [according to the rule](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/compositing/types/color/z_combine.html#inputs) - first is background, second - foreground. So your setup is like the [one here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/compositing/types/color/z_combine.html#examples)?

Comment: I played a bit with the order of the render layers and i had some results. So i think that the solution may be there. I will try it a bit as soon as i can.

Comment: Yes it is like that, but with several render layers(about 14) and Z combine nodes.

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit the question with the screenshot of the nodesetup and if possible a blend file? Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files.

Comment: I added an image but the file wheights 900Mo...

Comment: If you are creating this in 3D view why not use an ortho camera and simply move the objects in front or behind each other. They will to change size due to the orthographic camera lens

Comment: It could be a solution, but my camera is moving in depth, so it has to be in perspective so that the éléments get bigger as we approach them.

Comment: I made a test file with less assets....and i don't see any problem. You can download it here <img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png‌​?bid=3406" />
edit: After some tests i may have fond the solution thanks to you guys! It's on this link: 
 
I made a test file with less assets....and i don't see any problem. You can download it here <img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png‌​?bid=3406" />