# Blender 2.79 (rendering 6 render layers)

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

So Im working on an animation using 2.79's Internal render and I need to render 6 different render layers so that rendering the animation won't be so slow (because as of now its taking hours to render one frame). I need to know what kind of node set up am I looking at to make this happen because I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried Z passes, mix and add nodes and nothing gets the result i want. Can anyone help??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use alpha over, can chain as many as needed. Simple example, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/how-can-i-combine-two-render-layers

Comment: z-combine should be your friend: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81251/how-can-i-z-combine-multiple-render-layers